# position_dodge not dodging in geom_point plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point, position-dodge

I have a dataframe called `pollen_agg`.Here is its structure with `dput(pollen_agg)`:

```
pollen_agg <- structure(list(taxa = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("G. andrewsii", 
"G. puberulenta", "G. x billingtonii"), class = "factor"), site = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("BS", 
"HRP", "LHF", "SHP", "SPNP", "SRD"), class = "factor"),
presence.of.hybrids = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("absent", 
"present"), class = "factor"), percent_germination_mean = c(71.3333333, 
71.1111111, 88, 79, 21.1111111, 64, 70.5555556, 51.3333333, 65.8888889, 
45.1111111, 75.2222222, 71, 40.3333333, 81.6666667, 42.5555556, 
64.4444444), percentage_germination_se = c(4.6706332, 0.7286043, 
5.0037023, 2.8738927, 6.2341156, 7.535103, 2.7844365, 21.5432382, 
3.8216408, 8.0377197, 2.5410215, 13.5660251, 3.0061665, 3.7118429, 
0.8678055, 2.8888889)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to plot the points with error bars for this data and here is the chunk of code I am using for that:

```
ggplot(pollen_agg, aes(x = presence.of.hybrids, 
                       y = percent_germination_mean, 
                       color = taxa)) +
  scale_color_manual('Taxa', values = c('#a1d99b', '#9ebcda', '#8856a755')) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = percent_germination_mean - percentage_germination_se, 
        ymax = percent_germination_mean + percentage_germination_se),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
    width = 0.2
  ) +
  labs(title = "Percentage Germination",
       x = "Presence of Hybrids",
       y = "Percent Germination",
       color = "Taxa") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
```

But even with `position_dodge` in the code, my points and error bars are not dodging (see below).

[image]

Comment: Dodging works. For each `presence.of.hybrids` the points and error bars are dodged by `taxa`. However, there are also multiple `Site`s.

Comment: Ahh, okay, you are right. How would I factor in Site then with position_dodge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `aes(fill = site)` to `ggplot` and then add `guides(fill = "none")` to remove its legend.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(pollen_agg, aes(x = presence.of.hybrids, 
                       y = percent_germination_mean, 
                       color = taxa,
                       fill = site)) +
  scale_color_manual('Taxa', values = c('#a1d99b', '#9ebcda', '#8856a755')) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = percent_germination_mean - percentage_germination_se, 
                    ymax = percent_germination_mean + percentage_germination_se),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), width = 0.2) +
  labs(title = "Percentage Germination",
       x = "Presence of Hybrids",
       y = "Percent Germination",
       color = "Taxa") +
  theme_classic() +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>